# What happened to Angela Ashford?

Tags: resident-evil

The main plot around *Resident Evil: Apocalypse* centres on the characters having to find Angela Ashford in Racoon City so that her father, Charles Ashford, will tell them how to escape with his daughter. They manage this and at the end of the film when the group takes Alice out of the Umbrella facility Angie is seen in the back of the car.

However, in *Resident Evil: Extinction* Angie is missing and no explanation is given to her whereabouts that I am aware of. Of course quite a bit has happened since then, with the group splitting up and Jill Valentine presumably being taken hostage by Umbrella.

There is some mention to an incident that happened in Detroit so presumably something could have happened there to her.

> **White Queen:** Her powers would appear to have grown at a geometric rate since her escape from the Detroit facility.
>
> [...]
>
> **Carlos Olivera:** Alice, what happened to you? Why did you leave after Detroit?
>
> **Alice:** I didn't have a choice. They were using me.
>
> **Carlos Olivera:** What do you mean?
>
> **Alice:** They were tracking me. I couldn't be around you. Any of you. I would've gotten you all killed.
>
> **Carlos Olivera:** That's why you disappeared?
>
> **Alice:** Broke into an Umbrella facility and hacked into their computers downloaded the satellite trajectories and stayed off the grid.
>
> <sub>*Resident Evil: Extinction*</sub>

What happened to Angela Ashford?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of looking around this is apparently answered in the novelisation for *Resident Evil: Extinction*. In short when Alice was captured at the Detroit facility Dr. Isaacs programmed her to obey his orders, as we've seen a few times in the films, and one of these is to kill Angie.

> Peering into the SUV’s backseat, he added, “And I see you brought a friend. Very considerate, as we were wondering what happened to Dr. Ashford’s unfortunate daughter.” He sighed. “Still, I’m afraid she’s not terribly useful. The form of the T-virus her late, lamented father infected her with bears very little resemblance to what’s floating about in the air now. It’s mutated far beyond her ability to be useful to us.” Isaacs straightened up and looked right at Alice. “So I’m afraid you’re going to have to kill her.”
>
> Without hesitating, Alice unholstered her weapon and aimed it right at Angie.
>
> <sub>*Resident Evil: Extinction*, Chapter 16</sub>

> The bullet ripped through Angela Ashford’s head, splattering her brains all over the SUV’s rear window.
>
> In her mind, Alice screamed, Noooooooooooooooooooooooooo!
>
> <sub>*Resident Evil: Extinction*, Chapter 17</sub>

Comment: This is what my answer included, as well. :)

Comment: @INTERESTING Yeah turned out I had a copy of the eBook on my computer that I forgot I had and had yet to read it so just searched it for "Angela" and read the surrounding pages.

Comment: Nice. Glad you found it!

Comment: I will say bad writing

Comment: @AnkurRathee - Noooooooooooooooooooooooooo!

Answer (score 0):

## We don’t know...

The movie does not actually tell us what happens to her. According to [this](https://moviemorgue.fandom.com/wiki/Angela_Ashford) Wikia article,

> Angela makes no appearance in the third RE film and no explanation is given on-screen as to what happened to her.

However, in the book version of this, we find out that Angela and her friends are being chased by the Umbrella.

The same Wikia article says,

> However, the novelisation of Extinction reveals that Alice and her friends are pursued by Umbrella as the T-virus begins sweeping the United States.

Comment: Why don't you include the part of the wikia article that actually answers how she dies rather than saying We don't know?

Comment: Your question is unclear as to whether you are asking about the movie or novel. “We don’t know” applies to the movie.

Comment: The question is asking about the franchise as a whole, the movie and novel are canon to each other per my understanding.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Then please be clearer and identify that statement in your question.

Comment: There's nothing to identify, it is implicit that information from all of the canon material is fine.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You can’t just assume that others know that you are looking for answers from the movie AND the books. I believe that others, like me, would assume that you want answers from the movie.

Comment: I won't take this conversation further but yes I can. The tag is for the whole franchise and the books and movies are in the same canon. It is implicit that answers can draw from all of the canon material unless I specify I don't want answers from the books.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot There are no other tags for the books or movies. This is why it can be confusing.